# Want employee list of those whose start date was Mar-07?

Tags: sql, oracle

| M_ID | M_NAME | DEPT_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M001 | Richa | D001 | 27-Jan-07 | 27-Feb-07 | 150000 |
| M002 | Nitin | D002 | 16-Feb-07 | 16-May-07 | 40000 |
| M003 | AJIT | D003 | 8-Mar-07 | 8-Sep-07 | 70000 |
| M004 | SHARVARI | D004 | 28-Mar-07 | 28-Mar-08 | 120000 |
| M005 | ADITYA | D002 | 27-Apr-07 | 27-Jul-07 | 40000 |
| M006 | Rohan | D004 | 12-Apr-07 | 12-Apr-08 | 130000 |
| M007 | Usha | D003 | 17-Apr-07 | 17-Oct-07 | 70000 |
| M008 | Anjali | D002 | 2-Apr-07 | 2-Jul-07 | 40000 |
| M009 | Yash | D006 | 11-Apr-07 | 11-Jul-07 | 85000 |
| M010 | Nalini | D007 | 15-Apr-07 | 15-Oct-07 | 9999 |

I want to filter out employees that have start_date of Mar-07 I tried below query for the same but no rows got selected .Is my approach wrong?

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMP_TABLE
WHERE START_DATE LIKE '%Mar-07%';
```

Also my table structure is like this:

```
Name        Null? Type
M_ID              VARCHAR2(4)
M_NAME            VARCHAR2(20)
DEPT_ID           CHAR(4)
START_DATE        DATE
END_DATE          DATE
SALARY            NUMBER(6)
```

Comment: @SadlyFullStack I want **-Mar-07 regardless of any date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP_TABLE WHERE START_DATE LIKE '%Mar-07%';
```

relies on implicit conversion of every date to a string using your session NLS settings, and then string comparison. While that could work, it looks like maybe your NLS settings don't seem to match that format - PL/SQL Developer might be formatting the dates itself - or you're actually seeing `MAR-07` and aren't matching the case properly.

You can see your NLS settings by selecting `TO_CHAR(START_DATE)`, or by querying the `nls_session_parameters` view.

In any case, it would be better to search for a range of dates, rather than converting to strings:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP_TABLE
WHERE START_DATE >= DATE '2007-03-01'
AND START_DATE < DATE '2007-04-01'
```

Note that this will only find dates in 2007, while your original would include 1907, 1807 etc. - but that's probably what you want really.

Comment: I tried for 2007 and got it with the same query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole

Comment: How to compare datetime e.g I want details of 'START_datetime' greater than the value 2007-03-01 7:00:00 am

Comment: @Faisal - use `to_date('2007-03-01 07:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`, or `cast(timestamp '2007-03-01 07:00:00' as date)`. (Or if you're comparing with a timestamp rather than a date, the latter without the `cast()`; or `to_timestamp()`.)